# To what width should I limit my hexdump output in posts?

Tags: discussion, policy, formatting

The default for many programs which output a hexadecimal dump of data is often 16 columns of octets.  Defaults for binary or octal dumps are often different, but usually something similar to that width.
However, that could be awkward for users on mobile devices with narrow displays.  Add the offsets and the US-ASCII rendition on either side, and it can be quite wide in a monospaced font — especially if you separate each octet for better visibility.

If there isn't a recommended maximum width for GameDev Stack Exchange, then perhaps it should be discussed here.

I ask this here rather than on the [mother of all metas](https://meta.stackexchange.com) because I think the needs of different sites would have some bearing on this.  (Also, I think that the aforementioned site is a disaster that should be avoided like the plague, but whatever.)

Answer (score 2):

Format to whatever width seems appropriate for your question.

I don't think this is something we need a rigid standard for. We certainly don't worry too much about the line width of regular source code people post.

If you want to try to find a way to format your question so it reads well on mobile as well, great. But I wouldn't worry too much about it. The vast majority of questions and answers we get here don't look amazing on mobile no matter you slice them.

Comment: That's a good point:  if readability is important, then the width should vary if it helps whatever text best convey useful information.  Personally I disagree that we should ignore a certain format of presentation simply nothing else here does, but that is, of course, beyond the scope of this meta site.